How to make specific keyframe on that object to spin?
I got idea about make record spinning. but I wanna make it start spin on frame 40th. with make z angle move +2 repeatly. anyway to do it?

Hello what do you mean by move +2 repeatly?

sorry. I mean I wanna make z angle spinning +2 each frame go.

Create a first keyframe on frame 40, then another at the end of the frame range with a value twice that of the frame #, then hit T > Linear.

is there anyway to control speed when it go?

You can modify the value of the end keyframe if you want to make it faster overall, or set the interpolation to bezier and adjust the curves if you want to make it speed up over time :)

Oke. Thanks man!
